# Add new action to route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I got these actions in users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index #default action
    ...
  end

  def new #default action
    ...
  end

  def another_new
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  def another_create
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to be able to 
`/users/another_new` and call from some sort of link `:method => :another_create`
to make `/users/another_new`

I got the following config/routes.rb

```
get '/users/another_new' :to => 'users#another_new'
resources :users
```

my question is if this is the correct way to add the `get` and how I add the another_create method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

in your config/routes.rb file do this

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'another_new'
    post 'another_create'
  end
end
```

Also have a look [HERE](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for clear understanding of concepts.

Hope this helps you dude :)

Comment: Dude you are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 4):

try this in routes.rb

```
match "/users/another_new " => "users#another_new", :as => 'another_new'
```

then you can do

```
link_to "MyUrl", another_new_path
```

this should work. Good luck.

Comment: The order of lines inside routes.rb is very important. The custom path (within objects) must appear above and before the resources :objects definition.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that you shouldn't have `:method => :another_new`. Your options for `:method` are `:get`, `:put`, `:post`, and `:delete`, and the one you use should match how you defined the action in routes.